# How to replace a specific row from a CSV file?

Tags: java, opencsv, apache-commons-csv

Is it possible to access a specific row in a CSV file and replace a specific field in it? E.g. like in this pseudo code:

```
Row row = csvFile.getRow(123);
row.getField(2).set("someString");
```

Tried [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) and [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), but can't figure out how to do it with them. Only way I can think of is to iterate through a file, store everything in a new object and create a file, but that doesn't seem like a good way.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Replace Line In Text File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039980/java-replace-line-in-text-file)

Comment: "that doesn't seem like a good way" <-- but _that_ is the way. You never replace text in a file inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a [duplicate of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307972/editing-csv-files-design-implementation) to me.

I am not sure about how to do it with apache but I am sure they have the same mechanisms.  In openCSV you would create an CSVReader to your source file and a CSVWriter to your destination file.  Then read a record at a time, make any desired changes and write it out.

Or, if the file is small, you can do a readAll and writeAll.

But if you want to do it all in the same file read my comments [in the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307972/editing-csv-files-design-implementation).