# Using shell script to redesign a CSV file

Tags: excel, perl, shell, csv

Currently I am using a Perl script that parses a log file and outputs a CSV file in this format:

```
$ read_scalepack.pl HR00169_07.log 

mosaicity  0.52 -  1.59

SG & cell: p21    64.3    78.1    67.0    90.0    96.8    90.0            



Resolution    Measured    Unique  Redun.  %Complete  R-value  I/sigI


Overall       50.00-2.40   60827       23031    2.6       89.1    0.073     11.3 
First Shell   50.00-5.17   7173        2431     3.0       91.9    0.044     21.1 
3 sig Shell   2.85-2.70    6473        2446     2.6       95.4    0.316     3.4 
Penult Shell  2.59-2.49    4149        2056     2.0       80.1    0.370     2.4 
Last Shell    2.49-2.40    3105        1722     1.8       66.9    0.343     2.1

Rejected observations.  Number: 1599   Percent: 2.6
```

I then use a very long method of importing this into separate worksheet in Excel, copying values in the format I want to the "needed" sheet then deleting the imported CSV sheet (painful to watch). What I need is to either edit the Perl script (which I have no experience with) or use a shell script to have the CSV file be as follows:

```
p21 64.3 78.1 67.0 90.0 96.8 90.0 0.52-1.59 50.00-2.40 60827 23031 2.6 89.1 0.073 50.00-5.17 7173 2431 3.0 91.9 0.044 2.49-2.40 3105 1722 1.8 66.9 0.343 2.1
```

Basically one long line of statistics instead of stacked statistics with words.

I am using in one line the values from ("SG and cell", "mosaicity", "Overall", "First Shell", "Last Shell"). So I am ignoring some lines as they are not useful.

I researched the following article: [*Editing CSV Files (Design Implementation)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307972/editing-csv-files-design-implementation)

This person seems to be doing what I want to do, however they do not show exactly how, or at least the part I need.

I am also attaching a part of the Perl script in case it is better to approach it from that end, but again I have very little experience with Perl (warning Perl script is long).

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

...

        #
        #initialize
        $int_over_sigma_cutoff = 2.95;
        $flag_correct_lp       = 0;

        # get information on file
        if ( defined($last_file) ) {
            @stat_list = stat( $images_directory . '/' . $images_dir_list[$last_file] );
            $date_time = localtime( $stat_list[9] );
            $date_time =~ s/^\s+//;    # remove white space at beginning of line
            @date_parts = split( / +/, $date_time );
            $date = $date_parts[2] . '-' . uc( $date_parts[1] ) . '-' . $date_parts[4];
        }
    }

    return $date;
}

sub read_xscale_lp {
    #
    my $junk;
    my $flag_sg_cell   = 0;
    my $flag_by_shells = 0;
    #
    # Read XSCALE.LP log file
    while ( <> ) {
        #
        # get space group
        if (/ THE DATA COLLECTION STATISTICS REPORTED BELOW ASSUMES:/) {
            $flag_sg_cell = 1;
        }
        #
        # get unit cell parameters
        elsif ($flag_sg_cell) {

            $line = $_;
            chomp($line);
            $line =~ s/^\s+//;    # remove white space at beginning of line

            @line_parts = split( / +/, $line );

            if (/ SPACE_GROUP_NUMBER=/) {
                $space_group = &get_space_group_name( $line_parts[1] );
            }
            elsif (/ UNIT_CELL_CONSTANTS=/) {
                @cell         = @line_parts[ 1 .. 7 ];
                $flag_sg_cell = 0;
            }
        }
        #
        # get rejected measurements and total number of measured reflections
        elsif (/REFLECTIONS REJECTED/) {

            $line = $_;
            chomp($line);
            $line =~ s/^\s+//;    # remove white space at beginning of line

            @line_parts             = split( / +/, $line );
            $number_rejected        = $line_parts[0];
            $overall_measured_w_rej = $line_parts[3];
        }
        #
        # test whether column 10 will be Rmrgd-F or CC(1/2)
        elsif (/ Rmrgd-F/) {
            $column10 = "Rmrgd-F";
        }
        elsif (m| CC\(1/2\)|) {
            $column10 = "CC1/2";
        }
        #
        # Find table and set flag
        elsif (/ SUBSET OF INTENSITY DATA WITH SIGNAL\/NOISE >= \-3.0 AS FUNCTION OF RESOLUTION/) {

            $flag_by_shells = 1;
            $is             = 0;

            for ( $i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++ ) {
                $junk = <>;
            }
        }
        #
        # Make sure table flag is turned off
        elsif (/ SUBSET OF INTENSITY DATA WITH SIGNAL\/NOISE >= \-2.0 AS FUNCTION OF RESOLUTION/) {
            $flag_by_shells = 0;
        }
        #
        # Get information about R-values, I/sigI, etc.
        elsif ($flag_by_shells) {

            $line = $_;
            chomp($line);
            $line =~ s/^\s+//;    # remove white space at beginning of line
            $line =~ s/%//g;      # remove percentage sign from numbers

            @line_parts = split( / +/, $line );
            #
            # Get overall values
            if ( $line =~ /total/ ) {
                $overall_measured = $line_parts[1];
                $overall_unique   = $line_parts[2];

                #       $overall_theoretical[is] = $line_parts[3];
                $overall_complete     = $line_parts[4];
                $overall_rvalue       = $line_parts[5] / 100;
                $overall_int_over_sig = $line_parts[8];

                #       $overall_r_redun_i[$is] = $line_parts[9];
                if ( $column10 eq 'Rmrgd-F' ) {

                    #       $overall_r_redun_f[$is] = $line_parts[10];
                }
                elsif ( $column10 eq 'CC1/2' ) {
                    $line_parts[10] =~ s/\*//;
                    $overall_cc_onehalf = $line_parts[10] / 100.;
                }

                $flag_by_shells = 0;
            }
            #
            # Store individuals shells in arrays
            else {

                if ( $is > 0 ) {
                    $low_res[$is] = $high_res[ $is - 1 ];
                }

                $high_res[$is] = $line_parts[0];
                $measured[$is] = $line_parts[1];
                $unique[$is]   = $line_parts[2];

                #       $theoretical[is] = $line_parts[3];
                $complete[$is]     = $line_parts[4];
                $rvalue[$is]       = $line_parts[5] / 100;
                $int_over_sig[$is] = $line_parts[8];

                #       $r_redun_i[$is] = $line_parts[9];
                if ( $column10 eq 'Rmrgd-F' ) {

                    #       $r_redun_f[$is] = $line_parts[10];
                }
                elsif ( $column10 eq 'CC1/2' ) {
                    $line_parts[10] =~ s/\*//;
                    $cc_onehalf[$is] = $line_parts[10] / 100.;
                }

                $is++;
            }
        }
    }
    #
    # Get overall low and high resolution
    if ( !defined( $low_res[0] ) ) {
        $low_res[0] = 50.;
    }

    $overall_low_res  = $low_res[0];
    $overall_high_res = $high_res[$#high_res];
}

sub read_mrfana {
    #
    # read autoPROC mrfana file and reduce binning to 10
    my $line;
    my @line_parts;
    my $flag_table = 0;
    my $ishell     = 0;
    my $jshell     = 0;
    #
    while (<>) {
        if (/binning will be in/) {

            $line = $_;
            $line =~ s/ +//;    # delete spaces at beginning of line
            chomp($line);

            @line_parts       = split( / +/, $line );

            $no_of_shells     = $line_parts[4];
            $no_of_new_shells = $no_of_shells / 10;

            if ( $no_of_new_shells != int($no_of_new_shells) ) {
                $flag_not_integer = 1;
            }
        }
        elsif ( defined($flag_not_integer) && /binning for run/ ) {

            $line = $_;
            $line =~ s/ +//;    # delete spaces at beginning of line
            chomp($line);

            @line_parts       = split( / +/, $line );

            $no_of_shells     = $line_parts[7];
            $no_of_new_shells = $no_of_shells / 10;

            if ( $no_of_new_shells != int($no_of_new_shells) ) {
                die "$no_of_new_shells not evenly divisible by 10\n";
            }
            else {
                undef($flag_not_integer);
            }
        }
        elsif (/^            Resolution      \#uniq   \#R\w\w\w /) {
            $line       = <>;
            $flag_table = 1;
        }
        elsif ( $flag_table == 1 ) {

            if (/^ -------/) {

                if ( $ishell != 10 ) {

                    $high_res[$ishell] = $line_parts[2];

                    if ( $unique[$ishell] > 0 ) {
                        $rvalue[$ishell]       = $rvalue[$ishell] / $unique[$ishell];
                        $int_over_sig[$ishell] = $int_over_sig[$ishell] / $unique[$ishell];
                        $complete[$ishell]     = 100. * $complete[$ishell] / $unique[$ishell];
                        $redundancy[$ishell]   = $measured[$ishell] / $unique[$ishell];
                    }
                }
                else {
                    next;
                }
            }
            elsif (/^ Total/) {

                $line = $_;
                $line =~ s/ +//;    # delete spaces at beginning of line
                chomp($line);

                @line_parts           = split( / +/, $line );

                $overall_low_res      = $line_parts[1];
                $overall_high_res     = $line_parts[3];
                $overall_unique       = $line_parts[4];
                $overall_measured     = $line_parts[5];
                $overall_rvalue       = $line_parts[6];
                $overall_int_over_sig = $line_parts[13];
                $overall_complete     = 100. * $line_parts[14];
                $overall_redundancy   = $line_parts[16];

                if ( $#line_parts <= 17 ) {
                    $number_rejected = 0;
                }
                elsif ( $#line_parts >= 25 ) {
                    $number_rejected
                            = $line_parts[18]
                            + $line_parts[19]
                            + $line_parts[20]
                            + $line_parts[21]
                            + $line_parts[22]
                            + $line_parts[23]
                            + $line_parts[24]
                            + $line_parts[25];
                }
                else {
                    $number_rejected = $line_parts[18];
                }
                last;
            }
            else {

                $line = $_;
                $line =~ s/ +//;    # delete spaces at beginning of line
                chomp($line);

                @line_parts = split( / +/, $line );

                if ( $jshell % 10 == 0 ) {
                    $low_res[$ishell]      = $line_parts[0];
                    $unique[$ishell]       = $line_parts[3];
                    $measured[$ishell]     = $line_parts[4];
                    $rvalue[$ishell]       = $line_parts[5] * $line_parts[3];
                    $int_over_sig[$ishell] = $line_parts[12] * $line_parts[3];
                    $complete[$ishell]     = $line_parts[13] * $line_parts[3];
                }
                else {
                    $unique[$ishell]   = $unique[$ishell] + $line_parts[3];
                    $measured[$ishell] = $measured[$ishell] + $line_parts[4];
                    $rvalue[$ishell]   = $rvalue[$ishell] + $line_parts[5] * $line_parts[3];
                    $int_over_sig[$ishell]
                            = $int_over_sig[$ishell] + $line_parts[12] * $line_parts[3];
                    $complete[$ishell] = $complete[$ishell] + $line_parts[13] * $line_parts[3];
                }

                if ( $jshell % 10 == 9 ) {

                    $high_res[$ishell] = $line_parts[2];

                    if ( $unique[$ishell] > 0 ) {
                        $rvalue[$ishell]       = $rvalue[$ishell] / $unique[$ishell];
                        $int_over_sig[$ishell] = $int_over_sig[$ishell] / $unique[$ishell];
                        $complete[$ishell]     = 100. * $complete[$ishell] / $unique[$ishell];
                        $redundancy[$ishell]   = $measured[$ishell] / $unique[$ishell];
                    }

                    $ishell++;
                }

                $jshell++;
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}

sub read_xengen {
    #
    my $i;
    my $junk;
    my $flag_sg_cell      = 0;
    my $flag_redundancy   = 0;
    my $flag_int_over_sig = 0;
    #
    while (<>) {
        if (/Statistical Treatment of Crystallographic Data for/) {
            $flag_sg_cell = 1;
        }
        #
        # read through 2 blank lines and "Crystal Description:"
        elsif ($flag_sg_cell) {
            #
            # get space group
            if (/Crystal Spacegroup\:/) {

                $line = $_;
                chomp($line);
                $line =~ s/^\s+//;    # remove white space at beginning of line

                @line_parts = split( / +/, $line );

                $line_parts[5] =~ s/\,//;
                $space_group = &get_space_group_name( $line_parts[5] );
            }
            #
            # get unit cell parameters
            elsif (/Real-Space Parameters\:/) {

                $_    = <>;    # parameters are on next line
                $line = $_;
                chomp($line);
                $line =~ s/^\s+//;    # remove white space at beginning of line

                @line_parts   = split( / +/, $line );

                @cell         = @line_parts[ 0 .. 5 ];
                $flag_sg_cell = 0;
            }
        }
        elsif (/Summary of Observation Redundancies by Shells\:/) {

            for ( $i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++ ) {
                $junk = <>;
            }

            $is              = 0;
            $flag_redundancy = 1;
        }
        elsif ($flag_redundancy) {

            $line = $_;
            chomp($line);
            $line =~ s/^\s+//;    # remove white space at beginning of line

            @line_parts = split( / +/, $line );
            #
            # Get overall values
            if ( $line =~ /Totals\:/ ) {

                #       $overall_theoretical = $line_parts[2];
                $overall_unique = $line_parts[3];

                if ( $line_parts[2] > 0 ) {
                    $overall_complete = 100 * $line_parts[3] / $line_parts[2];
                }
                else {
                    $overall_complete = 0;
                }

                $overall_measured = $line_parts[13];
                $flag_redundancy  = 0;
            }
            else {

                if ( $is > 0 ) {
                    $low_res[$is] = $high_res[ $is - 1 ];
                }

                $high_res[$is] = $line_parts[0];

                #       $theoretical[$is] = $line_parts[2];
                $unique[$is] = $line_parts[3];

                if ( $line_parts[2] > 0 ) {
                    $complete[$is] = 100 * $line_parts[3] / $line_parts[2];
                }
                else {
                    $complete[$is] = 0;
                }
                $measured[$is] = $line_parts[13];
                $is++;
            }
        }
        elsif (/Summary of Reflection Intensities and R-factors by Shells\:/) {

            for ( $i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++ ) {
                $junk = <>;
            }

            $is                = 0;
            $flag_int_over_sig = 1;
        }
        elsif ($flag_int_over_sig) {

            $line = $_;
            chomp($line);
            $line =~ s/^\s+//;    # remove white space at beginning of line

            @line_parts = split( / +/, $line );
            #
            # Get overall values for I/sigI and R-value
            if ( $line =~ /Totals\:/ ) {
                $overall_int_over_sig = $line_parts[2];
                $overall_rvalue       = $line_parts[17] / 100;
                $flag_int_over_sig    = 0;
            }
            #
            # Store individual shells in arrays for I/sigI and R-value
            else {
                $int_over_sig[$is] = $line_parts[2];
                $rvalue[$is]       = $line_parts[17] / 100;
                $is++;
            }
        }
    }
}

sub check_for_scala_log {
    my @dir_pieces = split( /\//, $_[0] );
    my $line;
    my @line_parts;
    my $scala_log;
    my $flag_dataset_id  = 0;
    my $flag_space_group = 0;
    my $count            = 0;
    #
    if ( $#dir_pieces > 0 ) {
        $scala_log = join( '/', @dir_pieces[ 0 .. $#dir_pieces - 1 ] ) . '/scala.log';
    }
    else {
        $scala_log = 'scala.log';
    }
    if ( -e $scala_log ) {

        open( LOG, "<$scala_log" ) || die "Unable to open $scala_log\n";

        while (<LOG>) {

            if ( m|Dataset ID, project/crystal/dataset names, cell dimensions, wavelength|
                && $flag_dataset_id == 0 ) {

                $flag_dataset_id = 1;

                $line            = <LOG>;    # blank line -- skip
                $line            = <LOG>;    # Dataset ID project name
                $line            = <LOG>;    # crystal name
                $line            = <LOG>;    # dataset name
                $line            = <LOG>;    # cell dimensions
                $line =~ s/ +//;             # delete spaces at beginning of line
                chomp($line);

                @cell = split( / +/, $line );

                $line = <LOG>;    # wavelength
                $line =~ s/ +//;    # delete spaces at beginning of line
                chomp($line);

                $wavelength = $line;
                $count      = $count + 6;
            }
            elsif ( /Space group =/ && $flag_space_group == 0 ) {
                $flag_space_group = 1;
                $line             = $_;
                $space_group      = substr(
                    $line,
                    index( $line, "\'" ) + 1,
                    rindex( $line, "\'" ) - ( index( $line, "\'" ) + 1 ) );
                $space_group =~ s/ //g;
                $count = $count + 2;
            }

            $count++;
        }
    }
}

sub check_for_aimless_log {
    my @dir_pieces = split( /\//, $_[0] );
    my $line;
    my @line_parts;
    my $aimless_log;
    my $flag_average_unit_cell = 0;
    my $flag_space_group       = 0;
    #
    if ( $#dir_pieces > 0 ) {
        $aimless_log = join( '/', @dir_pieces[ 0 .. $#dir_pieces - 1 ] ) . '/aimless.log';
    }
    else {
        $aimless_log = 'aimless.log';
    }

    if ( -e $aimless_log ) {

        open( LOG, "<$aimless_log" ) || die "Unable to open $aimless_log\n";

        while (<LOG>) {

            if ( /Average unit cell/ && $flag_average_unit_cell == 0 ) {

                $flag_average_unit_cell = 1;

                $line = $_;
                $line =~ s/ +//;    # delete spaces at beginning of line
                chomp($line);

                @line_parts = split( / +/, $line );

                @cell = @line_parts[ 3 .. 8 ];
            }
            elsif (/Wavelength/) {

                $line = $_;
                $line =~ s/ +//;    # delete spaces at beginning of line
                chomp($line);

                @line_parts = split( / +/, $line );

                $wavelength = $line_parts[1];
            }
            elsif (/Space group\:/) {

                $line = $_;
                $line =~ s/ +//;    # delete spaces at beginning of line
                chomp($line);

                $space_group = substr( $line, index( $line, "\:" ) + 1 );
                $space_group =~ s/ //g;
            }
            elsif (/Average mosaicity/) {

                $line = $_;
                $line =~ s/ +//;    # delete spaces at beginning of line

                @line_parts = split( / +/, $line );

                $average_mosaicity = $line_parts[2];

                if ( $mosaicity_min >= 1000. ) {
                    $mosaicity_min = $average_mosaicity;
                }

                if ( $mosaicity_max <= -1000. ) {
                    $mosaicity_max = $average_mosaicity;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

sub read_scl_in {
    #
    # read scl.in, extract some information, and store scl.in in list
    my $i_zone = 0;
    my $line;
    my @line_parts;
    my $flag_est_err = 0;
    my $file;
    #
    my @dir_pieces = split( /\//, $_[0] );

    if ( $#dir_pieces > 0 ) {
        $file = join( '/', @dir_pieces[ 0 .. $#dir_pieces - 1 ] ) . '/scl.in';
    }
    else {
        $file = 'scl.in';
    }
    #
    # Open old file
    #    open(INFILE,"<$file") or die "unable to open $file";
    open( INFILE, "<$file" ) or return;

    while (<INFILE>) {

        $line = $_;
        chomp($line);

        if (/number of zones/) {

            $line =~ s/^\s+//;    # remove white space at beginning of line

            @line_parts = split( / +/, $line );

            $n_zone = $line_parts[3];
        }
        elsif (/estimated error/) {
            $flag_est_err = 1;
        }
        elsif ( /space group/ && !defined($space_group) ) {
            $space_group = 1;
        }
        elsif ( $flag_est_err == 1 ) {

            $line =~ s/^\s+//;    # remove white space at beginning of line

            @line_parts = split( / +/, $line );

            if ( $i_zone == 0 ) {
                @est_err = @line_parts;
            }
            else {
                push( @est_err, @line_parts );
            }

            $i_zone = $i_zone + scalar(@line_parts);

            if ( $i_zone == $n_zone ) {
                last;
            }
        }
    }

    close(INFILE);
}

sub read_output_sca {
    #
    # read output.sca to get cell parameters when reading scale.out for statistics
    my $junk;
    my $line;
    my @line_parts;
    my $file;
    #
    my @dir_pieces = split( /\//, $_[0] );

    if ( $#dir_pieces > 0 ) {
        $file = join( '/', @dir_pieces[ 0 .. $#dir_pieces - 1 ] ) . '/output.sca';
    }
    else {
        $file = 'output.sca';
    }
    #
    if ( -e $file ) {

        open( SCA, "<$file" );
        $junk = <SCA>;    # Skip first and second lines
        $junk = <SCA>;
        $line = <SCA>;    # Unit cell and space group are third line
        close(SCA);

        $line =~ s/^\s+//;    # remove white space at beginning of line

        @line_parts  = split( / +/, $line );

        @cell        = @line_parts[ 0 .. 5 ];    # Unit cell parameters are first 6 values
        $space_group = $line_parts[6];           # Space group is 7th value
    }
}

sub get_space_group_name {
    #
    # Use space group dictionary to translate from number to name
    $space_group_number = $_[0];

    open( SGDIC, "</ap/bms/mmc/space.dic" );

    while (<SGDIC>) {

        if (/^(P|A|B|C|I|F|R)/) {

            $line = $_;
            chomp($line);

            if ( substr( $line, 21, 3 ) == $space_group_number ) {
                @line_parts = split( / +/, $line );
                $space_group = $line_parts[0];
                last;
            }
        }
    }

    return $space_group;
}
```

Comment: Hi Josh. This question as-is is off-topic here. SO is for getting help with specific code-related questions (eg: "this is my snippet of code, but on line X, I can't figure out why Y isn't doing Z. I've tried this, that and the other"). It's not meant as a code writing service, code review service or overall "why doesn't this program work". Please see [SO rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You're best off either learning how to code, or hire someone to write an application to your specifications. If you attempt it yourself, come back here with specific questions as you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the output from your Perl script through this. It will generate the result you require

You can pass the previous output as a parameter on the command line, or you can use a pipe to pass output of the previous script to this one without saving a file at all

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @data;

while ( <> ) {

    s/\s*-\s*/-/;

    my @fields = grep /\d/, split;

    pop @fields if /Overall|First Shell/;

    if ( /mosaicity|Overall|First Shell|Last Shell/ ) {
        push @data, \@fields;
    }
    elsif ( /SG & cell/ ) {
        unshift @data, \@fields;
    }
}

print join(' ', map @$_, @data), "\n";
```

#### output

```
p21 64.3 78.1 67.0 90.0 96.8 90.0 0.52-1.59 50.00-2.40 60827 23031 2.6 89.1 0.073 50.00-5.17 7173 2431 3.0 91.9 0.044 2.49-2.40 3105 1722 1.8 66.9 0.343 2.1
```

Comment: Thanks Borodin! Apologies for not following the rules, I will most definitely pay attention to these things in the future. Your solution works perfectly!